# Can't get Materialize Picker to work in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, materialize

I am new to React and can't seem to get my Materialize Picker to work at all.

I have all the Materialize installed and imported.

It displays correctly and opens correctly but when I select a date, I get an error displaying every time and can't figure out why.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeBy' of undefined

I have added all my code below for my test page where it's currently sitting.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToDo } from '../../store/actions/todoActions';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import M from "materialize-css";
//import moment from 'moment';

class AddToDo extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    content: '',
    assignTo: '',
    completeBy: new Date(),
    format: 'ddd d, mmm',
    //formatMoment: 'ddd D, MMM'
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.addToDo(this.state);
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
  handleCancel = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
  canBeSubmitted() {
    const { title, content, assignTo } = this.state;

    return title.length > 0 && content.length > 0 && assignTo.length > 0;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');

    M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      format: this.state.format,
      container: 'body',
      onSelect: function(date) {
        this.setState({ completeBy: this.state.completeBy }); // Errors here
      },
      autoClose: true
    });

    M.FormSelect.init(selects, {});
  }
  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted();

    if (!auth.uid) {
      return <Redirect to='/login' />
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="white" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Add a new todo item</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" id='title' onChange={ this.handleChange } autoFocus />
            <label htmlFor="title">Todo title <span className="red-text">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={ this.handleChange }></textarea>
            <label htmlFor="content">Todo content <span className="red-text">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <select id="assignTo" onChange={ this.handleChange }>
              <option value="default" disabled selected>Please select</option>
              <option value="Kyle">Kyle</option>
              <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
              <option value="Tony">Tony</option>
            </select>
            <label htmlFor="assignTo">Assign todo to <span className="red-text">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="completeBy">To be completed by</label>
            <input
              id="completeBy"
              type="text"
              className="datepicker dateset"
              // defaultValue={ moment(this.state.completeBy).format(
              //   this.state.formatMoment
              // )}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 l1">
              <button className="btn pink lighten-1 col s12" disabled={!isEnabled}>Add</button>
            </div>
            <div className="col s12 l1">
              <button onClick={this.handleCancel} className="btn yellow darken-2 col s12">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addToDo: (todo) => dispatch(addToDo(todo))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToDo)
```

Some may recognise the code base as I was following Net Ninja tutorials but adding to it for my learning.  I have also had a look at the following [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842589/how-do-i-correctly-capture-materialize-css-datepicker-value-in-react) question and tried their solution as its the same code as mine also but it does not work for me.

I have checked my `package.json` and I am using "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2" and I am not using `react-materialize`.

**Screenshots**

*Initial load*

[image]

*Click in the date field*

[image]

*Set a date, picker closes and get*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I use arrow functions when I define callbacks. Because it handles the scope of this differently than a function. Try to replace onSelect callback to an arrow function:

```
M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  format: this.state.format,
  container: 'body',
  onSelect: (date) => {
    this.setState({ completeBy: this.state.completeBy }); 
  },
  autoClose: true
});
```